# Why is my function get_absolute_url is merging my domain into my website name?

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I'm using the Django sitemap framework, and I have to use the function get_absolute_url to render the site URL in the sitemap. However, I'm facing a problem because my link is becoming: exampleio.io instead of example.io.

My function in my model is it:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('packages', args=[self.name])
```

My function in the sitemap.py

```
class ExampleSitemap(Sitemap):

    protocol = "https"
    changefreq = "weekly"
    priority = 0.7
    limit = 500

    def items(self):
        return Example.objects.all()
```

I'm getting:

```
<sitemap>
<loc>http://exampleio.io/sitemap-examples.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check django /admin, under the Sites section.  Make sure your site is correctly named there.

Comment: Man, you saved many hours of my life time. Thank you so much, I hope you have a great week!